# How to use ngFor for an accordion to loop multiple times in Angular

Tags: angular, toggle, accordion, ngfor

I have the below code for creating accordion using plus and minus icons. I have handled the toggle functionality as well. But now I want to loop this inside ngFor for multiple set of elements . I am not sure how to do this.
Basically i have a resultArray which is a json . I need to loop through resultArray json to get the heading and description and place it as accordion heading and accordion description. I am not sure how to replace the accord.id dynamically.

### HTML

```
<div *ngFor = "let resulArray of resultArray">
     <div *ngFor="let accord of accordian;">
                  <div (click)="toggle(accord.id)" id="accordionTitle{{accord.id}}" class="accordionTitle active">{{accord.label}}
                    <i class="fa fa-minus" id="minus{{accord.id}}"></i>
                  </div>
                  <div id="{{accord.id}}" *ngIf="accord.id == 0" class="hidden-data show">
</div>
</div>
```

The toggle below is to apply styles and change of icons from plus to minus to the accordion. When toggle function is called

### ts.

```
this.accordian = [{
      id: 0, label: 'Accordion title'
    }];

toggle(id) {
    this.x = document.getElementById(id);
    this.y = document.getElementById('accordionTitle' + id);
    if (this.x.className.indexOf('show') === -1) {
      this.x.className += ' show';
      this.y.className += ' active';
      document.getElementById('minus' + id).classList.remove('fa-plus');
      document.getElementById('minus' + id).classList.add('fa-minus');
    } else {
      /*  this.x.className = this.x.className.replace('hide', ''); */
      this.x.className = ' hide';
      /*   this.y.className = this.y.className.replace('', ''); */
      this.y.className = 'accordionTitle';
      document.getElementById('minus' + id).classList.remove('fa-minus');
      document.getElementById('minus' + id).classList.add('fa-plus');
    }
}
```

### JSON

```
resultArray = {
      'status': 'SUCCESS',
      'responseCode': '000',
      'errorMessage': null,
      'cboRequestList': [
          {
              'seqNo': 1,
              'applicableFor': '0',
              'applicableForText': 'Hide',
              'displayDesc': null,
              'displaySeqNo': 1,
              'description': 'ABCDisplayDesc1',
              'type': 'W',
              'content': null,
              'field1': null,
              'field2': null,
              'field3': null,
              'field4': null,
              'markerId': null,
              'markerLastModifiedTime': null,
              'countryCode': null,
              'languageCode': null,
              'commentMaker': null
          },
          {
            'seqNo': 2,
            'applicableFor': '0',
            'applicableForText': 'Hide',
            'displayDesc': null,
            'displaySeqNo': 1,
            'description': 'ABCDisplayDesc1',
            'type': 'W',
            'content': null,
            'field1': null,
            'field2': null,
            'field3': null,
            'field4': null,
            'markerId': null,
            'markerLastModifiedTime': null,
            'countryCode': null,
            'languageCode': null,
            'commentMaker': null
        }
      ],
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your json file as a code block?

Comment: @monogate I have pasted the json code

Comment: @monogate I have found the below solution . Now I want to apply color to li tag . I used ngClass but it doesnt change. Can u help me on this

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="row justify-content-md-center businessOffice">
  <div class="col-md-9 business">
      <h3 class="mainTitile">Help</h3>
      <p class="bottom-30">
          How may i help you today ?
      </p>
<div *ngFor="let resultArrayText of cboRequestListArray; let i = index">
      <ul class="list-group bottom-30" (click)="toggle[i] = !toggle[i]">
          <li class="list-group-item"  ng-class="{'activateToggle': toggle[i], '': !toggle[i]}" >
              {{resultArrayText.description}}
              <i class="fa" [ngClass]="toggle[i] ? 'fa-plus': 'fa-minus'" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </li>
          <div *ngIf="!toggle[i]" class="container activateToggle">
            <p class="content-30">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
              Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
              1500s
            </p>
              <p>
                <strong>Refer for more informations:</strong> <a>Click View Documents</a>
              </p>
              </div>
            </ul>
</div>


        </div> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **[ngClass]** wrong.

You should first declare the class name and then evaluate true or false with your variable.

example:

```
<i class="fa " [ngClass]="{'fa-plus': someBoolean1, 'fa-minus': someBoolean2 }" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

This expression means that **fa-plus** will be applied when **someBoolean1** will be **true** and **fa-minus** will be applied when **someBoolean2** will be **true**

You can apply as much classes as you want with ngClass.

In your case you should handle the true or false evaluation according to **toggle[i]** like this:

```
<i class="fa " [ngClass]="{'fa-plus': toggle[i], 'fa-minus': !toggle[i]}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Regarding how to apply styles:
By using **[ngStyle]="{'color': exp }"** for each element you need. Notice 'exp' means expression which should be a variable or a function to evaluate to a color name or code.

Example:

```
exp = 'green';
<h1 [ngStyle]="{'color': exp }">My Text</h1>
```

Comment: ok but how do i apply colors? . I need to apply different set of colors for expanded and collapsed states

Comment: No you are not getting my point. My question was to apply colors to expanded li and collapsed li